# NSProxy and forwardInvocation: invoke called within a block causes nil return value

Tags: ios, block, retain, nsinvocation, nsproxy

I am using a `NSProxy` subclass and `forwardInvocation:` for capturing calls to my Backend API object (a shared instance).

*Some Background information:
I want to capture the API calls so I can check everytime if I have to refresh my authentication token. If yes I just perform the refresh before.*

The method parameters (of `invocation`) contain blocks.

Some simplified code:

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation {

    [invocation setTarget:self.realAPI];
    [invocation retainArguments];

    // Perform refresh call and forward invocation after
    // successfully refreshed
    if (authenticationRefreshNeeded) {

        [self.realAPI refreshWithBlock:^(NSObject *someObject) {

            [invocation invokeWithTarget:self.realAPI];

        }];
    }
    // Otherwise we just forward the invocation immediately 
    else {

        [invocation invokeWithTarget:self.realAPI];
    }

    return;
}
```

I am already calling `retainArguments` so my blocks and other parameters don't get lost because of the late execution of `invokeWithTarget:` (`refreshWithBlock:` makes an async API call).

Everything works fine so far - BUT:

The **return value** of invocation is always `nil` when `invokeWithTarget:` is performed within the refresh block. Is there any way to retain the return value (like the arguments)?

Any hints? Suggestions?

---

**Update**

As response to @quellish:
The problem is that the return value is of type `NSURLSessionDataTask` (that I use to show an activity indicator) which I read directly after making the call. But the proxy does not forward the call immediately so the return value is not there - of course (I was blind).
What would be a possible workaround? Can I return a placeholder value or how can I know as caller when the method gets invoked so I can retrieve the return value later?

Comment: Can you update the question with where/how you are reading the return value? Is your invocation itself nil when you are calling ``getReturnValue:``?

Comment: Did so. Facepalm for the rest of the evening... Any hints how I can solve the problem? Or is there another way to intercept the API calls for performing another async task before (without having to do the refresh check in every API method...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform an operation when your invocation is complete, passing the result:

```
if (authenticationRefreshNeeded) {

    [self.realAPI refreshWithBlock:^(NSObject *someObject) {
        NSURLSessionDataTask    *resultTask = nil;
        [invocation invokeWithTarget:self.realAPI];
        [invocation getReturnValue:&resultTask];
        if (completion != nil){
            completion(resultTask);
        }
    }];
}
```

Where `completion()` is a block that takes an `NSURLSessionDataTask` as a parameter. Blocks can be used as callbacks, which make them well suited to what you are trying to do ("when I'm done, do this() ") Ideally, this would have been passed into the method containing the above - but since this is `forwardInvocation:` , that gets a little more... challenging. You could set it as a property on this proxy object and read it from there.

Another approach would be to extend UIApplication with a category or informal protocol with a method like `addDataTask:` which you could call instead of your block, which would hand off responsbility for the "i just added a data task" to another receiver, most likely the application's delegate (and you can extend the UIApplicationDelegate protocol with a new method, `application:didAddDataTask:` to handle this). It sounds like your data task and activity indicator are application-level concerns, which may make this a good fit.

That said, I have some experience with almost *exactly* the problems you are trying to solve (token based authorization). I would suggest taking at a look at how [ACAccountStore](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/ACAccountStore.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011021-CH1-SW17) approaches this problem , it may offer some ideas for alternative implementations.

Comment: I don't know...this all seems to be a bit hard. But many thanks for your answer. For the question I did ask, this is the right one... even if I have to go on looking for a good solution.

Comment: Yeah the problem you're trying to solve - making a request as a prerequisite for the "real" request (for token authentication) is a nasty one. Again, look at how ``requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion`` works, that should give you some direction that's simple and fairly reliable.